# how to extract the different fields from the text file by the general expression in php

Tags: php, regex

```
207.46.13.93 - - [31/Mar/2012:19:43:19 +0530]  GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1 404 613 -   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Double_bounce_sender?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:06:51 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/rdiff/TWiki/NewUserTemplate?rev1=1.3&rev2=1.2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4523
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:10:02 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/hsdivision HTTP/1.1" 200 6291
```

Comment: Please, ask a question correctly... i see just a raw log...

Comment: How to get this log seperated by each fields by using regex?

Answer (score 0):

It's far better to use a log parser but you could use this regex to extract log information :

`(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[\s-]+(?<date>\[.*\])[\s"]+(?<method>\w+)\s+(?<url>[^\s]+)\s+(?<protocol>[^\s]+)[\s"]+(?<status>\d+)\s+(?<length>\d+)([ -]+(?<useragent>.*))?`

**Explanation**

`(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)` An IP => *ip* group

`[\s-]+` Either a whitespace or an hyphen, at least one time

`(?<date>\[.*\])` [ followed by any character but a ] => capture *date*

`[\s"]+` Either a whitespace or a double-quote, at least one time

`(?<method>\w+)` some word characters => capture *method*

`\s+` at least one whitespace

`(?<url>[^\s]+)` Any character but a whitespace, at least one time => capture *url*

`\s+` at least one whitespace

`(?<protocol>[^\s]+)` Any character but a whitespace, at least one time => capture *protocol*

`[\s"]+` Either a whitespace or a double-quote, at least one time

`(?<status>\d+)` some digit characters => capture *status*

`\s+` at least one whitespace

`(?<length>\d+)` some digit characters => capture *length*

`([ -]+(?<useragent>.*))?` Optional spaces or hyphens followed by user-agent => capture *useragent*

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tSw3J1/3)